# Differences Between `then(...).catch(...)` and `spread(...).fail(...)` in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I would like to ask what are the differences between `then(...).catch(...)` and `spread(...).fail(...)` methods. Can you give some insights on how and when should I use them?

Comments are highly appreciated.

Notes:
* I am using **sequelize v3.1.0** and **tedious v1.11.0**.

Comment: You have two pretty different questions here.  You're going to have better luck if you split them up.

Comment: Based on sequelize's `package.json`, it looks like they're using the [Bluebird promise library](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md).  You might want to start there.